# SLT Can not activate configurations

Tags: activation, error-log, slt

In the SAP GUI, transaction LTRC:

In SLT we have 3 configurations all are red / not activated.
Activating all configurations does not change anything.
Neither is it possible to activate a single configuration.

Where can I get further information about what is wrong?

Is there an error log and if so how can I access it?

Also what are the reasons that could lead to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As first step in debugging SLT issues is

Call Transaction `SM21` and view the logs at the time the issue occured